# Find type parameter of generic function in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, types, type-parameter

recently I've came up upon an interesting issue. Say I have a generic function, how could I receive the type of it's type parameter (type of 'T'), similarly to Parameters or ReturnType only for the type parameter. The issue is illustrated in the next example (the function 'GetTypeParameter' is the function which I wonder how to implement):

```
interface A {
}

function Foo<T extends A>() {
    return 'something';
}

// The wanted ability
type ACopy = GetTypeParameter<Foo> // this will return the type A;
```

Comment: I think you'd need to have at least an argument to the function and/or return value that is of type `T`. That's probably the only way to `infer` the generic type

Comment: Agree with @Chase, you should either return `T` or use `T` as argument type

Comment: Another vote for what @Chase said. Besides, TS throws an error if no function params includes the generic type, so there must always be a way to access it via the `Parameters` utility type.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is only possible if your generic function has *at least one argument* of type `T` (the generic param), or the function has a return value of type `T` (the generic param).

With those constraints, you can use [`infer`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types) to get pretty close.

```
interface Foo {
    fooProp: string;
}

// Function with return type of `T`, where `T` is a generic param extending `Foo`
declare function func1<T extends Foo>(): T;
// Function with argument type of `T`, where `T` is a generic param extending `Foo`
declare function func2<T extends Foo>(a: T): number;

// Extract generic param from function return type
type GenericOf<F> = F extends (...args: any[]) => infer A ? A : never;

// Extract generic param from function argument type
type GenericOf_<F> = F extends (a: infer B, ...args: any[]) => any ? B : never;


let f1: GenericOf<typeof func1>;
 // ^ Foo

let f2: GenericOf_<typeof func2>;
 // ^ Foo
```

Try it out on [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4FgBQyRyMmAClOgA4BcyAzmFKAOYDcBAvgQQCYQIANnCgoYAVxAIwwdCBKSEARgA8AFWQQAHpBC96aTAD4AFAEo6ajvn5CRYxTLkKpAJnWadEPQYzpTcJYWyCDiALYARtDWBGAAnlQoAOLe0MAIAPIwKqhGyAC8aJ66+sgmAHSVIiz0dHAgcQDaALpmBXmgMNDIAILIAPy9yHQgEABu0bEJyanMmTAA+jl5hajF3qUmgcid3QBCADTIleXVtcj1Ta3tFw0DyHvDIeOT+ASCEGAkSnQpo3NZFTxRLoGAuZRGazIAD00OQAD1kAALdATKDI6AQd6fEiuX6zdJZJbAiCg8GuSEEGFwxEotEY0Q8fBAA).

The thing is though, this is really not exhaustive or robust. You *have to know* whether you need to use `GenericOf` or `GenericOf_` on the function, that means you *have to know*  whether the function has an argument of its corresponding generic type or a return value of its corresponding type.

The drawbacks don't end there. There's no way to actually make sure the function you pass *is a generic function* to begin with.

See this type?

```
type GenericOf<F> = F extends (...args: any[]) => infer A ? A : never;
```

That's basically just `ReturnType<F>`, there's nothing *special* to it. It only *becomes special* when you, the programmer, **assume** it is an actual generic function that uses its generic param as its return type.

Unfortunately, I believe this is the closest you can get at this time. I'd love to be proven wrong though!